# CollectionView duplicate inside UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I am using custom tabelview cell to display movies and I need to display movie genre using collectionView  like this :
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSBRH.png)

First in cellForRowAt from ViewController I use this code to create array to gather genres( item is genres list )

```
            geners.removeAll()

            for element in item {
                if (popular[indexPath.row].genreIds?.contains(element.id!))!{
                    geners.append(element.name ?? "")
                }
            }


       cell.genreView.genrView = geners

      return cell
```

Second in the Custom View Class, I used tableViewCell : 
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMxAy.png)

```
class CustomView: UIView {
@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var genrView : [String] = []{
    didSet {
        print(genrView)
    }
}



    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell",for:indexPath) as? CustomCell
    cell?.label.text = genrView[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
}
```

The problem is: The Collectionview is duplicated/repeated in tabelview after cell number 5. It is not showing right genres to all movies 
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6GcD.png).
[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4qOt.png)

Although the array is working right 
[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfs26.png)

Comment: what results do you have when you place a breakpoint in ` collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt`?

Comment: for collection view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simplest way to fix this will be to replace

```
print(genrView)
```

with:

```
collectionView.reloadData()
```

in your

```
var genrView : [String] = []{
    didSet {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by that? is cellForItemAt never called? if aria of strings is there, cells should update